# What is actualy causing Curl error (code 6): getaddrinfo() thread failed to start

Tags: php, laravel, apache-kafka, librdkafka

I'm using laravel to produce data to confluent cloud kafka, but recenly I got some error message
Curl error (code 6): getaddrinfo() thread failed to start, what is actualy causing this error ?

the ulimit is already increased

here is my code to produce data to kafka

```
namespace App\Services;
use App\Helpers\LogActivity;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class KafkaProduceServices{
    public function produce($topic, $data, $flushTime = 60000){
        Log::info("CALL KafkaProduceServices FOR TOPIC ".$topic);
        try {
            $conf = new \RdKafka\Conf();
    
            $conf->set('bootstrap.servers', env('KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER'));
            $conf->set('security.protocol', env('KAFKA_SASL_PROTOCOL'));
            $conf->set('sasl.mechanism', env('KAFKA_SASL_MECHANISM'));
            $conf->set('sasl.username', env('KAFKA_SASL_API_KEY'));
            $conf->set('sasl.password', env('KAFKA_SASL_API_SECRET'));
    
            $producer = new \RdKafka\Producer($conf);

            $topic_produce = $producer->newTopic($topic);
            $topic_produce->produce(RD_KAFKA_PARTITION_UA, 0, $data);

            $result = $producer->flush($flushTime);
    
            if (RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR_NO_ERROR !== $result) {
                Log::info("END CALL KafkaProduceServices(ERROR) FOR TOPIC ".$topic);
                return [
                    'error' => true,
                    'message' => 'Was unable to flush, messages might be lost!, error: '. json_encode($result),
                ];
            }

            Log::info("END CALL KafkaProduceServices(SUCCESS) FOR TOPIC ".$topic);
            return [
                'error' => false,
                'message' => 'Message was sended'
            ];
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            Log::info("END CALL KafkaProduceServices(ERROR CATCH) FOR TOPIC ".$topic);
            LogActivity::makeErrorLog('CORE','KAFKA PRODUCE',$topic,$th->getMessage(),json_encode($data)); // sent error to slack
            return [
                'error' => true,
                'message' => $th->getMessage()
            ];
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using this function in queue laravel

Comment: `getaddrinfo` error might mean the address is incorrect... What is the value of `env('KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER')`

Comment: The value is contain the address of the kafka server, with 9092 port, but the error is not always happen